# How to use a nested array in a struct?

Tags: go

I have the following structure:

```
    type InputData struct {
        fullname string `bson:"fullname"`
        parts []string `bson:"parts"`
        alt string `bson:"alt"`
    }
```

Now I want to use this structure. But how I can add parts?
I mean something like:

```
myvar := InputData{fullname:"Sample", parts: ["A", "B", "C"], alt: "Something"}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note: There are no arrays in your code. `[]string` is a slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a string slice.
Example: https://play.golang.org/p/_u8VHyM_KzD

```
myvar := InputData{fullname:"Sample", parts: []string{"A", "B", "C"}, alt: "Something"}
```